# How does HtmlUnitDriver render the page?

Tags: java, jsp, selenium, webdriver

I use selenium-java-2.32.0
I used selenium earlier, but I haven't ever worked with HtmlUnitDriver.

There is an html-page, let it be localhost/mainPage

I create new HtmlUnitDriver:

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_17);
driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
```

Then I navigate to my page:

```
driver.get(page);
```

where page is "localhost/mainPage".
On this page there is a button. And when I try to click it:

```
driver..findElement(By.id("button_ok")).click();
```

I get the following exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: You may only interact with visible elements
Build info: version: '2.32.0', revision: '6c40c18', time: '2013-04-09 17:23:22'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_43'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitWebElement.verifyCanInteractWithElement(HtmlUnitWebElement.java:290)
at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitWebElement.click(HtmlUnitWebElement.java:140)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:41)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.click(Unknown Source)
at com.epam.sbrf.pages.Page.click(Page.java:85)
at com.epam.sbrf.utils.TestMethodStatusPay.searchBrakByLinumAndFinishTransfer(TestMethodStatusPay.java:87)
at com.epam.sbrf.pages.PaySearchPage.searchBrakByLinumAndTransferFinished(PaySearchPage.java:678)
at com.epam.sbrf.test.CheckAscertainStatusPay.sendFromControlToAscertain(CheckAscertainStatusPay.java:67)
at com.epam.sbrf.test.CheckAscertainStatusPay.checkStatusFromAscertainToReturnedToPayer(CheckAscertainStatusPay.java:44)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

I tryed to debug it, and what I figured out:
1. driver.getCurrentPage() - "localhost/mainPage". It's correct.
2. drivet.getPageSource() - contains no "button_ok".

So, I have the page and driver navigated to this page. There is a button on this page. But in source code of the page there is no button - maybe there is a problem?
The page is constructed by many parts, it's jsp. I actually don't understand how does it work - the project is old and big, and I have no contacts of it's previous developers.

And the question is - how does HtmlUnitDriver render the page? If source code of the page contains no element - HtmlUnitDriver won't be able to interact with it?

Comment: Just for kicks - if you use the Firefox or Chrome driver?

Comment: If I use Firefox driver, it works well. But I have to run tests on CI, that's why I want to use HtmlUnitDriver

Comment: Why can't you use FF on a CI server?

Comment: I will do it if the problem won't be solved. But it's not very convenient variant - servers are on customer side.

Comment: I guess there's some client-side javascript which creates the button_ok element. Can you post the javascript? It might help identify what's going wrong. Also, can your script interact with any other dynamically-generated elements at all?

Answer (score 0):

Try [GhostDriver](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver) with [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) browser. It's good alternative to HtmlUnitDriver in order to work in headless mode. PhantomJS is based on WebKit and renders modern pages more reliable.